# ampersand url encoding issues

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm hard coding a url to have something like this:

"/ContactUs.aspx?mode=New&form=Contact"

the page is rendering the below as part of the url...

mode=New&amp%3bform=Contact

so the page breaks when i rediriect to this page. and try to Request.QueryString["form"].

how can i make it behave with the & symbol

Comment: Can you show us the Code in front where you are doing this? Some controls can encode the text inside them.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried escaping the ampersand using the HTML entity `&amp;` ? Ampersands in URLs must be escaped. You should also URL Encode any values passed in the query string - I think `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` does that (off top of my head).

For instance, your URL should be:

```
/ContactUs.aspx?mode=New&amp;form=Contact
```

However, you don't need to do this if you are using an `<asp:HyperLink />` , as `NavigateUrl` properties are automatically encoded.

See [this article on URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) for why you need do this. In .NET you can use the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) to do this. This is also accessible via `Server.UrlEncode` of current `HttpContext.`